# List posts related to category on a div

Tags: posts, categories, wp-query

i want to display posts related to selected category at the same page(on a different div).
What i want is as the image attached, when i click the category name on the left side, all related posts must be listed on right. 
Thanks in advance
**EDIT**  i couldn't set up the logic, the code is not my issue. i couldn't realize how to solve the matter. i dont ask for codes, i just want an idea 
[image: Display of my page]

Comment: To go with your wishlist, what have you done so far. Please edit your question and add the code you already have, working or not

Comment: i'm sorry but i couldn't set up the logic, the code is not the issue, i couldnt realize how to solve the matter. i dont ask for codes, i just want idea

Comment: StackExchange sites are not well-suited for "asking for ideas" type questions. Instead, questions are intended to be within the scope of solving a specific problem. For the WordPress Development stack, that generally means, *I've tried code X to accomplish Y, but Z happened instead.*

Comment: I do know the usage logic of exchange sites, if i could create the logic coding was the easiest part.

Comment: @ChipBennett I like your comment. Well stated

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start. Create a template called `content-related.php`

Inside that paste the following code

```
<?php
/**
 * The default template for displaying realted posts
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Pieter Goosen
 * @since pietergoosen 1.0
 */



wp_reset_postdata();
    global $post;

    // Define shared post arguments
    $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
    if ($categories) :
        $category_ids = array();
        foreach($categories as $individual_category) 
            $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;

        $args=array(
                'category__in' => $category_ids,
                'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                'posts_per_page'=>3, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
                'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1
            );

        $query = new wp_query($args);

    if ( $query->have_posts() ): ?>

    <div class="related-posts block">

        <h4 class="heading">
            <?php _e('You may also like &hellip;','pietergoosen'); ?>
        </h4>

            <div class="related-posts group">

                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

 <--- YOUR LOOP GOES HERE--->

<?php endwhile; ?>

</div>

</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This code checks for the category (using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query))of the post that is displayed using `get_the_category($post->ID)`. From this, posts from this category is fetched. In this code, three posts (`'posts_per_page'=>3,`) will be displayed from the category of the post currently displayed. You can customize the query to suite your needs, also, you can customize your loop just the way you want to.

You can now call this in your `single.php` where you need to display your related posts using

```
get_template_part('content', 'related');
```

As for the styling, you will need to sort that out yourself. CSS related stuff is off-topic here BTW

Comment: i created a few divs and a custom function, and change visibbility of clicked div to display(the other ones are hidden. thus, i show just related posts for the moment. thanks for your solution, i will try it too, which one becomes useful i will use it.